# Include one big file or several smaller ones?

Tags: php, include

```
<?php include ('big_file.php');?>
```

`big_file` is about 25 KB, text only, and it is very uncomfortable for handling and editing.

If I split it into chapters, I got five smaller files, each about 7 KB and it seems there is no difference in time loading the page on localhost.

But still, is there any downside of this solution, especially about time loading on remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference when including one big file or just parts of the same file multiple times will be negligible to non-existent on local server (via local filesystem).

You also mention including files from remote server, then including multiple will make a difference over one, as for every include the server will make a separate request and that will bring extra overhead.

Also, if you expect to include .php source files over remote, then it will not workas `.php` files are parsed on the server side, so you will only be able to include the output of parsed `.php` files on remote server.

Comment: edvinas, all included files have a `.php` extension. If I understand you well, in this case there should be no difference in time loading?

Comment: If you're incuding files from a remote server, then there will always be an overhead; and if those files have a .php extension, and the remote server is properly configured to parse PHP, then those files will be parsed on the remote server and only the output that they generate will be sent back to your server to be included

Comment: Yes this is what I meant, but my wording wasn't proper I guess. I will update this.